# Is there a reliable means of determining if a sorted set contains "GEO" data?

Tags: redis

When you add a key in Redis using the `GEOADD` command the entry is saved as a sorted set (type: zset).

My question is, is there a way (using Lua perhaps?) to determine if the data in a sorted set is "GEO" data or not?

Answer (score 0):

Because geosets use sorted sets for storage, the two are identical in as far as Redis is concerned. Therefore, there's no built-in way to distinguish between them.